# How to : Add plugin with styles to custom element vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I created a separate plugin(visit-lib-traveller-counter-v3) and a custom element using vue 3. Then I added the plugin to custom element and run the project. But the styling of the added plugin not being affecting. I could not find where I missed.

Main.js of custom element( visit-lib-traveller-counter-v3 is the plugin)

```
import EntryComponent from './components/EntryComponent.ce.vue'
import { defineCustomElementWrapped } from './defineCustomElementWithStyles'

import localeList from './translations/localeList'

import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: 'enUS',
  fallbackLocale: 'enUS',
  messages: localeList
})
import travellerCounter from 'visit-lib-traveller-counter-v3'

customElements.define(
  'my-vue-element',
  defineCustomElementWrapped(EntryComponent, {
    plugins: [i18n, travellerCounter]
  })
)
import 'visit-lib-traveller-counter-v3/dist/style.css'
```

defineCustomElelemtWithStyles.js

```
import { defineCustomElement, h, createApp, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
export const defineCustomElementWrapped = (component, { plugins = [] } = {}) =>
  defineCustomElement({
    styles: component.styles, // <- this
    render: () => h(component),
    setup() {
      const app = createApp()

      // install plugins
      plugins.forEach(app.use)

      const inst = getCurrentInstance()
      Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context)
      Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides)
    }
  })
```

Comment: You need to inject the styles into the shadow DOM of the element at runtime. Please read [Web Components vs. Vue Components](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components#web-components-vs-vue-components): *"Shipping custom elements with shadow DOM scoped CSS today requires embedding the CSS inside JavaScript so that they can be injected into shadow roots at runtime."*